# Construction of biholomorphism

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega = \{ z \in \mathbb{D} : |Arg(z)| < \alpha\}$, where $\mathbb{D}$ denotes the unit disc in the complex plane, and the argument function takes values in $[-\pi,\pi)$,with $\alpha \in [0,\pi)$.

I want to construct a biholomorphism from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{D}$. I know about Möbius transformations, however I'd like to know how to start with this question. Should we first attempt to map it into the half-plane, and then map that to $\mathbb{D}$, or construct some other mapping?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you shouldn't expect to be able to do this solely in terms of mobius transforms.  Mobius Transforms take circles/lines to circles/lines, but $\Omega$ is decidedly neither a circle nor a line, so you'll need some other biholomorphism from $\Omega$ to a more suitable set (such as the upper half plane, as you suggest).

Comment: Yes. Could you help me in that regard? What could that suitable set be, and the transformation to that set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few standard tricks to construct biholomorphisms. You already know about Möbius transformations, which take circles to circles (where a line is just a circle through infinity). One important type is taking powers, which "opens up" angles in the way you would expect. So,

$$f_\beta(z)=z^\beta$$

will map $\Omega$ to the set $\{z\in\mathbb D\,:\,|\text{Arg}z|<\alpha\beta\}$. Choose $\beta=\frac\pi{2\alpha}$ and multiply by $i$ and we get the upper semicircle.

Now another "standard" biholomorphism you'll want to know if $z+\frac1z$, which maps the upper semicircle to the lower half plane. (It is a useful exercise to prove this.) Thus the map
$$g(z)=-z-\frac1z$$
maps into the upper half plane. Finally, we use the Möbius transofmration $\phi(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ to get the upper half plane to the unit disk. Composing these functions, we get
$$F(z):=\phi(g(if_{\frac\pi{2\alpha}}(z)))$$
is a biholomorphism from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb D$.

Comment: +1. Thank you very much for your answer. It was excellent reading.